# Microsoft Graph PowerShell: Export CSV List of Users with Managers Name and UPN

Tags: azure, powershell, visual-studio-code, microsoft-graph-api

I need to create a PowerShell script to export a list of users to a CSV from Azure AD to show their last sign in date which includes the users details such as name, email and job title as well as their manager and their display name and email too.

I have got the below working but not sure how to also include their last sign in information as well as the managers email address.

```
Connect-MgGraph

$logDate = Get-Date -Format "dd-MMM-yyyy"

$csvFile = "c:\temp\AllAADUsers_$logDate.csv"

Get-MgUser -All -ExpandProperty manager | Select DisplayName, UserPrincipalName, JobTitle, @{Name = 'Manager'; Expression = {$_.Manager.AdditionalProperties.displayName}} | Export-Csv -Path $csvFile
```

Comment: You need `AuditLog.Read.All` to get the user's last SignIn. Do you have that permission?

Comment: I do, yes. Just struggling to figure out the code to display all the properties I require. Believe I need to create a function and list it all in an array but struggling with that.

Comment: Looking at your code it seems right, the only thing you're missing is the `signInActivity` right? or what else are you missing?

Comment: So I'm missing signInActivity and I'm not sure how to also display the managers userPrincipalName, I'm currently only getting the managers displayName with that code. As it's an expanded property, not sure how to get it. Do I need to create an array?

Comment: I've just noticed that in the code I posted, I've put userPrincipalName after the manager.additionalproperties which is a mistake, it doesn't actually work. I've now edited it.

Comment: Ok, i'll try to answer in a bit unless somebody else answers. A bit busy right now

Comment: No worries, any help you can offer at all would be greatly appreciated. Only discovered Microsoft Graph PowerShell yesterday so still learning! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unfortunate but as of now the [**User Graph API**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-beta) doesn't support retrieving the user's `manager` and `signInActivity` in a single query, for this you would need to perform 2 queries for each user:

```bash
$getMgUserSplat = @{
    ExpandProperty = 'Manager'
    All            = $true
    Property       = @(
        'DisplayName'
        'UserPrincipalName'
        'JobTitle'
        'Manager'
    )
}

Get-MgUser @getMgUserSplat | ForEach-Object {
    $signIn = Get-MgUser -UserId $_.Id -Select SignInActivity

    [pscustomobject]@{
        DisplayName        = $_.DisplayName
        UserPrincipalName  = $_.UserPrincipalName
        JobTitle           = $_.JobTitle
        ManagerDisplayName = $_.Manager.AdditionalProperties['displayName']
        ManagerEmail       = $_.Manager.AdditionalProperties['mail']
        LastSignInDateTime = $signIn.SignInActivity.LastSignInDateTime
    }
} | Export-Csv path\to\myExport.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Works a treat, thank you so much!